# $P(A_n\space\text{i.o.})=0$ or $1$ according as $\sum_{n\geq 1}(1-F(\lambda_n))<\infty$ or $=\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. with distribution function $F$, let $\lambda_n\uparrow \infty$, and let $A_n=\{\max_{1\leq m\leq n}X_m>\lambda_n\}$. Show that $P(A_n\space\text{i.o.})=0$ or $1$ according as $\sum_{n\geq 1}(1-F(\lambda_n))<\infty$ or $=\infty$

Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}(1-F(\lambda_n))=\sum_{n\geq 1}P(X_n>\lambda_n)<\infty$ or $=\infty$, I can get $P(X_n>\lambda_n\space\text{i.o.})=0$ or $1$ accordingly. But I don't know what to do next. Any help appreciated.

---

Thanks to @DiegoFonseca, I understood that $A_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^{n}\left\{\omega |X_{m}(\omega)>\lambda_{n}\right\}$. I missed this part. But I could not get why $"<\infty"$ part is true?

Comment: Can you give us a more specific definition of $A_{n}$?

Comment: @DiegoFonseca there is nothing more written in the book.

Comment: Note that $A_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^{n}\left\{\omega |X_{n}(\omega)>\lambda_{n}\right\}$, then we have $$P(A_{n})=P\left(\bigcup_{m=1}^{n}\left\{\omega |X_{n}(\omega)>\lambda_{n}\right\}\right)=1-P\left(\bigcap_{m=1}^{n}\left\{\omega |X_{n}(\omega)\leq\lambda_{n}\right\}\right)=1-(F(\lambda_{n}))^{n}.$$
We know that $0\leq (F(\lambda_{n}))^{n}\leq F(\lambda_{n})\leq 1$, then $\sum_{n\geq 1} (1-F(\lambda_{n}))\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}P(A_n).$ Therefore, if $\sum_{n\geq 1} (1-F(\lambda_{n}))=\infty$ then $\sum_{n\geq 1}P(A_n)=\infty$, so by Borel–Cantelli lemma we have that $P(A_{n}\:i.o)=1$.

Comment: The problem is the other case. I think it might not be true because of the fact that $\sum_{n\geq 1} (1-F(\lambda_{n}))<\infty$ is not evident that this implies $\sum_{n\geq 1} 1-F(\lambda_{n})^{n}<\infty$.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca thanks for $A_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^{n}\left\{\omega |X_{n}(\omega)>\lambda_{n}\right\}$, I missed that. This is actually from durrett's Probability book. Problem $2.3.19$... Is $"<\infty"$ part really wrong. I want to know why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $(\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0,\infty)$ such that $\lambda_n \uparrow \infty$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $a_n>\lambda_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$
> 2. $\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} a_j > \lambda_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Once we have proved the result, we find that $$\left\{ \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} X_j > \lambda_n \, \, \text{i.o.}\right\} = \{X_n>\lambda_n \, \, \text{i.o.}\},$$ and the assertion follows from the considerations in your question.

Proof of the claim: Since

$$\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} a_j \geq a_n$$

it is clear that the first statement implies the second one. Now assume that

$$\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} a_j > \lambda_n \tag{1}$$

for infinitely many $n \in I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. For $n \in I$ define

$$r_n := \min\{1 \leq j \leq n; a_j> \lambda_n\}.$$

(Because of $(1)$ there has to exist at least one such $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$!) Since $\lambda_n$ is increasing and $r_n \leq n$, we then have

$$a_{r_n} > \lambda_n \geq \lambda_{r_n}$$

for all $n \in I$. This finishes the proof.